# Error when converting from base 64 string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a password stored in SQL. When decoding I get an error The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode.

Decrypt code:

```
string userEmail = Email1.Text;
string userPass = passW.Text;
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("My connection")
string query = "Select * from users Where email= '" + userEmail + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable()
sda.Fill(dtbl);
if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    string savedPasswordHash = dtbl.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    savedPasswordHash.Replace("-", "");
    byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(savedPasswordHash);
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(userPass, salt, 10000);
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
    int ok = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
            ok = 0;
            if (ok == 1) //good creds & redirect
```

Encrypt Code:

```
byte[] salt1;
new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt1 = new byte[16]);
var pbkdf21 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EmailTextBox.Text, salt1, 10000); 

byte[] hash1 = pbkdf21.GetBytes(20);
byte[] hashBytes1 = new byte[36];

Array.Copy(salt1, 0, hashBytes1, 0, 16);
Array.Copy(hash1, 0, hashBytes1, 16, 20);

string savedPasswordHash1 = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes1);
string commString = $"UPDATE users SET NewPassword = ('{savedPasswordHash1}') where Email = ('{email2}')";
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = connect;
        comm.CommandText = commString;
        connect.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
    }
```

Datatype of column is `nvarchar`

Comment: Please show the code for the insert part as well. Also checkout and give the data type of the password field in database. You might want to isolate your code more so check out what actually is in `savedPasswordHash`

Comment: This doesn't look right... shouldn't there be a column list after `Select`? `string query = "Select  from users Where email= '" + userEmail + "'";`

Comment: OT please use parameters instead of building values into a SQL string

Comment: @Emad I am getting 7408207-16186516-9228325 in the savedPasswordHash string

Comment: SavedPasswordHash.Replace doesn't do anything

Comment: @99fbirdls1 This is not base64 string. check out `savedPasswordHash1` right before it is set in db.

Comment: @Emad how do I fix this?

Comment: Please set a breakpoint right before your sql update and give me the value in `savedPasswordHash1`

Comment: @Emad  `savedPasswordHash` value is `BMYPmSZZQoHoBnjgx/La853c3K6gieWlJDehszC5wWnIQPHa`

Comment: Ok now this is a base64 string. Now how many columns does your `users` table have? And which one is the `NewPassword`

Comment: 28 Columns total

Comment: Which one is the `NewPassword`?

Comment: It is the 28th Column

Comment: Please. See the edit in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem is in your SQL code. You should never add values in the query like that. That creates the huge risk of SQL injection attack plus the sort of problem that you face.

The base64 string may contain characters that are not meant to go to a query string.

So change the encryption like this:

```
string commString = "UPDATE users SET NewPassword = @PasswordHash where Email = @Email";
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = connect;
        comm.CommandText = commString;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("PasswordHash", savedPasswordHash1);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", email2);
        connect.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
    } 
}
```

Also you can simplify the command creation but I don't want to change two things. You can fix that later on.

**--Edit--**

After going back and forth it's clear that the problem is in decrypt and not the encrypt part. You do what I said above or your code is seriously in danger.

```
string savedPasswordHash = dtbl.Rows[0][27].ToString(); //Change 1 to 27
```

Also remove the next line

```
//savedPasswordHash.Replace("-", ""); (Remove)
```

Comment: my `int ok =1` keeps equaling 0 now. Am I overlooking something?